# Fixed UIButton on footer on both iphone 4 & 5 with one piece of code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a button on the bottom left corner of the screen that jump up when I change the simulator to 4 inch. Is there a way to keep it fixed to the bottom regardless of the iphone resolution?

Comment: Did you create the button with code or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Are you requiring iOS 6? If so, are you using [Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1)?

Comment: Auto Layout is one option or the 'old approach': `UIView autoresizingMask`, don't forget to make the `superview` of the `UIButton` `autoresizesSubviews `

Comment: I'm ios 5 compatible so auto layout is not a possibility . (it's only ios 6 compatible right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using interface builder just select the control and do this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A quick followup. I've placed the button on the left bottom side of the screen. When I changed to back to 3.5 inch on the simulator the button stayed at the bottom but jumped to bottom right. Any idea why? (marking the autosizing down and left worked of course but I'm just wondering about the logic behind it.)

Comment: What autosizing settings were set when that happened? Since its only the vertical height changing thats not what I would expect to happen.

Comment: Just the down one. That's why it was weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it's frame regarding the screensize like :

```
MyButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, self.view.frame.size.height -60,100,50);
```